# Regarding File.Copy of a partial file

Tags: c#, file

I am monitoring a folder using FileWatcher in c#. When a file is created in a folder, my file creation event handler gets triggered. What will happen if the file is not full(it is a huge file and still being copied) and I call File.Copy on it to copy the file to a different location? Will the copy happen or will it fail? If the copy happens, will it copy the file completely? Will File.Copy wait for the file to be completely created, before it starts the copy or does it start copying even when the original file is still being copied?

Comment: All you have to do is to carry out a simple experiment; usually on the attempt to move such a file you'll have *exception thrown*: when creating and writing to file we usually create file with *exclusive rights* to prevent *partially written* file to be read, moved, copied etc.

Comment: you can just test it, with a big dummy file

Comment: Nothing much, you'll surely discover that File.Copy() fails with an IOException.  You have to wait until the program that is writing the file is done with it and no longer has a lock on the file.  Exactly how long that takes is unpredictable, you have to periodically retry.  Almost any question about FileSystemWatcher talks about this btw, be sure to research them.